# How do I create very large .gif files from .png frames, avoiding memory limitations?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, png, gif

I would like to create a `.gif` from single `.png` frames and am dealing with lots of very large files. The `.png` files are roughly `10GB` in total.

So far, I have done the following:

`ffmpeg   -framerate 30   -pattern_type glob   -i '*.png' -filter_complex "split[a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse"  out.gif`

Which works fine, unless the amount of `.png` files becomes to large. As far as I can tell, the problem lies in the `palettgen` filter, which exceeds free disk space, using up as much as `90GB`.

I have also tried creating separate `.gif` files, and then concatenating them, which lead to the first `.gif` looping over and over and the second `.gif` never being played at all.

Another thing I've tried was creating an intermediate `.mkv` file and a `.png` palette file, and using those to create the final `.gif`.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -i palette.png -lavfi paletteuse out.gif
```

That throws the following error:

```
Error while filtering: Internal bug, should not have happeneditrate=198092.4kbits/s speed=0.19x     
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Internal bug, should not have happened
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

The latter seems to be them most promising approach, so if someone could provide commands that might work, that would be great.